# json object returning 'undefined" values along with actual values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

So, I've looked through similar questions out here, but still couldn't find an answer to my query.
For some reason, I seem to get "undefined values along with my actual values in my json object. I receive these values from my php file. The code ffor the php file is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct rackID FROM rackusage where startTime like '%".$curdate."%'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){


        // Queries to get respective values to put inside my array

        $temp[] = array('id' => (int) $r['rackID']); 
        $temp[] = array('rackName' => (string) $rackname);
        $temp[] = array('uptime' => (int) $uptime); 
        $temp[] = array('downtime' => (int) $downtime); 
        $temp[] = array('utilization' => (int) $utilization);
    }   echo json_encode($temp);
```

The output string is as follows:

> [{"id":1},{"rackName":"xyz"},{"uptime":119},{"downtime":0},{"utilization":0},{"id":2},{"rackName":"abc"},{"uptime":122},{"downtime":0},{"utilization":0},{"id":3},{"rackName":"pqr"},{"uptime":114},{"downtime":0},{"utilization":0}]

The JS code is:

```
        function workwithdate(curdate){
            $.ajax({
               type: "Post",
                url: 'senddata.php',
                data:{'selectDate': curdate},
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        alert(data);
                        recData= $.parseJSON(data);
                        //recData = data;
                        console.log(recData);
                         alert(recData);
                         alert(recData.length);

                        $.each(recData, function(idx, la){
                          var someid = la.id;
                            console.log(someid);
                          var rName = la.rackName;
                            console.log(rName);
                          var rUptime = la.uptime;
                            console.log(rUptime);
                        });
       }
                }
            });
        }
```

My output looks like this:[image: Console Output]

TIA

Comment: Rather than having an object with a bunch of properties, senddata.php is returning an array populated with single-property objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one associative array per row, so:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $temp[] = array(
        'id' => (int) $r['rackID'], 
        'rackName' => (string) $rackname,
        'uptime' => (int) $uptime,
        'downtime' => (int) $downtime, 
        'utilization' => (int) $utilization
    );
}
```